# Error in creating foreign key in product table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key, create-table

I have created a table Suppliers n MySQL 
**Suppliers Description:**

```
Supplier_ID varchar(5) NOT NULL
Supplier_Name varchar(30)
Supplier_Address varchar(50)
Supplier_Contact int(12)
Supplier_Email varchar(30)
PRIMARY KEY(Supplier_ID)
```

Now,
I want to create table Products
**Products Description will be :**

```
Product_ID varchar(5) NOT NULL
Product_Name varchar(30)
Supp_Name varchar(30)
Product_Category varchar(20)
Unit_Price int(11)
Unit_In_Stock int(11)
PRIMARY KEY(Product_ID)
FOREIGN KEY(Supp_Name) REFERENCES Suppliers(Supplier_Name)
```

But when I am trying to create products table it's giving an **error**:

> ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'csm.products' (error:150)

CSM is a database name.

Comment: You should reference the ID and not the NAME

Comment: @VishalRaut What `juergen d` meant was to refer `Supplier_ID` column of Supplier table instead of `Supplier_Name` column. You can not have reference key referring to column which is not primary key.

Answer (score 1):

As @juergend also pointed out in a comment, you should reference the `Supplier_ID` field in your foreign key, not the `Supplier_Name`, also you should replace the `Supplier_Name` with the `Supplier_ID` field in your `products` table. I would also change the data type of the supplier id to an integer, possibly an auto incremented one.

The reasons are

1. You may have multiple suppliers with the same name
2. A supplier may change name over the time
3. It is lot more efficient to cross check a fixed length integer value over a long, variable length string.

Si, I would change the `products` table as follows:

```
Product_ID varchar(5) NOT NULL,
Product_Name varchar(30),
Supplier_ID int NOT NULL,
Product_Category varchar(20),
Unit_Price int(11),
Unit_In_Stock int(11),
PRIMARY KEY(Product_ID),
FOREIGN KEY(Supplier_ID) REFERENCES Suppliers(Supplier_iD)
```

`supplier` table:

```
Supplier_ID int NOT NULL [auto_increment]
Supplier_Name varchar(30)
Supplier_Address varchar(50)
Supplier_Contact int(12)
Supplier_Email varchar(30)
PRIMARY KEY(Supplier_ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Product_ID varchar(5) NOT NULL,
Product_Name varchar(30),
Supplier_ID varchar(5) NOT NULL,
Product_Category varchar(20),
Unit_Price int(11),
Unit_In_Stock int(11),
PRIMARY KEY(Product_ID),
FOREIGN KEY(Supplier_ID) REFERENCES Suppliers(Supplier_iD)
```

Comment: Can i make Supplier_ID and Supplier_Name both a primary key. Will that work ?

Comment: why would you have 2 primary key on same table ??

Comment: @VishalRaut You can not have two primary keys on one table. Even if you create composite primary key consisting of two columns you can not refer one of them as reference key. I won't solve the issue also. You can have more than one suppliers with same name so it will defeat the purpose of integrity.

Comment: Can a Supplier ID exist for more than one Supplier_name?You can create indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you reference ID not name, if you want to have name as reference make supplier name as primary and id as unique. Though having ID primary key is highly recomended